# Show that $\frac{\sin^3 \beta}{\sin \alpha} + \frac{\cos^3 \beta}{\cos \alpha} = 1$ with certain given $\alpha, \beta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Let $$\frac{\sin (\alpha)}{\sin (\beta)} + \frac{\cos (\alpha)}{\cos (\beta)} = -1 \tag{$1$}$$ where $\alpha, \beta$ are not multiples of $\pi / 2$. Show that
$$\frac{\sin^3 (\beta)}{\sin (\alpha)} + \frac{\cos^3 (\beta)}{\cos (\alpha)} = 1\tag{$2$}$$

I've tried to rewrite $(1)$ and insert into $(2)$ to get
$$ - 1 -  \frac{\sin^4 \beta \cos^2 \alpha + \cos^4 \beta \sin^2 \alpha}{\sin \alpha \sin \beta \cos \alpha \cos \beta} = 1 \\
\iff \frac{\sin^4 \beta \cos^2 \alpha + \cos^4 \beta \sin^2 \alpha}{\sin \alpha \sin \beta \cos \alpha \cos \beta} = -2$$

But I can't simplify any further, maybe there are some trig. identities I'm missing?

Comment: $$\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$$
$$\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin\theta\cos\theta$$
$$\cos(2\theta) = \cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta$$
$$\sin(\alpha \pm \beta) = \sin\alpha\cos\beta \pm \cos\alpha\sin\beta$$
$$\cos(\alpha \pm \beta) = \cos\alpha\cos\beta \mp \sin\alpha\sin\beta$$
$$\sin\alpha\sin\beta = \frac{1}{2}\left( \cos(\alpha - \beta) - \cos(\alpha + \beta) \right)$$
$$\cos\alpha\cos\beta = \frac{1}{2}\left( \cos(\alpha - \beta) + \cos(\alpha + \beta) \right)$$
$$\sin\alpha\cos\beta = \frac{1}{2}\left( \sin(\alpha - \beta) + \sin(\alpha + \beta) \right)$$

Comment: I tried and there seems to be no other way but to use the prosthaphaeresis trig formulas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eq.$(1)$ is equivalent to

$$\sin(a+b)=-\frac{1}2\sin(2b)\tag{3}$$

Now start from the LHS of Eq.$(2)$, and we will show it equals $1$

$$\begin{align}
\text{LHS}=\frac{\sin^3(b)\cos(a)+\cos^3(b)\sin(a)}{\sin(a)\cos(a)}\end{align}$$

Deal with the numerator:
$$\begin{align}
\text{Numerator}&=(1-\cos^2(b))\sin(b)\cos(a)+(1-\sin^2(b))\cos(b)\sin(a)\\
\\
&=\sin(a+b)-\cos^2(b)\cos(a)\sin(b)-\sin^2(b)\cos(b)\sin(a)\\
\\
&=\sin(a+b)-\frac{1}2\cos(a)\cos(b)\sin(2b)-\frac{1}2\sin(a)\sin(b)\sin(2b)~~~~~~~\text{use} ~~(3)\\
\\
&=\sin(a+b)+\sin(a+b)\cos(a-b)\\
\\
&=\sin(a+b)+\frac{1}2\sin(2a)+\frac{1}2\sin(2b)~~~~~~~\text{use} ~~(3)\\
\\
&=\frac{1}2\sin(2a)=\text{Denominator}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying by a common denominator gives:

$$\sin \alpha \cos \beta + \cos \alpha \sin \beta = -\cos \beta \sin \beta$$

which is the same as

$$\sin(\alpha + \beta) = -\cos \beta \sin \beta. \tag{1}$$

Now:

$$(\sin \alpha \cos \beta + \cos \alpha \sin \beta)(\sin^2 \beta + \cos^2 \beta) = -\cos \beta \sin \beta$$
$$\sin \alpha \cos \beta \sin^2 \beta + \cos \alpha \sin^3 \beta + \sin \alpha \cos^3 \beta + \cos \alpha \sin \beta \cos^2 \beta = -\cos \beta \sin \beta$$
$$\cos \alpha \sin^3 \beta + \sin \alpha \cos^3 \beta = -(\cos \beta \sin \beta + \sin \alpha \cos \beta \sin^2 \beta + \cos \alpha \sin \beta \cos^2 \beta)$$

We want the RHS to equal $\sin \alpha \cos \alpha$. Repeatedly using $(1)$ we get:

$$-(-\sin(\alpha + \beta) + \sin \alpha \cos \beta \sin^2 \beta + \cos \alpha \sin \beta \cos^2 \beta)$$
$$-(-\sin(\alpha + \beta) + \sin \beta \cos \beta (\sin \beta \sin \alpha + \cos \alpha \cos \beta))$$
$$-(-\sin(\alpha + \beta) + (-\sin(\alpha + \beta))(\sin \beta \sin \alpha + \cos \alpha \cos \beta))$$
$$-(-\sin(\alpha + \beta) - \sin(\alpha + \beta) \cos(\alpha - \beta))$$
$$= \sin(\alpha + \beta) + \sin(\alpha + \beta) \cos(\alpha - \beta)$$

and the rest follows from MathFail's answer.